# PHP: How to find occurrence of a * wildcard character in a string

Tags: php, string, wildcard

Maybe I'm asking a bit too banal question, but I really cannot figure out how to check for an occurrence of a wildcard (*) character in a string using PHP.

An example string: `*bcd` OR `ab*d` OR `abc*`

Whatever PHP function I try to use, it behaves unpredictably. I just need to know whether the wildcard character is or is not in a string. Thank you very much for replies!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/it/function.strstr.php

Comment: It's probably better if you show your code and string that is behaving "unpredictably". This is an easy task, so if you're having trouble we need the actual code.

Comment: @Fabio _"Note: If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function `strpos()` instead."_

Comment: @wise that is correct, but depends on what op needs to do after

Answer (score 4):

```
if (strpos($mystring, '*') === false) {
    echo "Wildcard was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "Wildcard was found in the string '$mystring'";
}
```

Based on the example at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php